# How to call javascript adapters from java adapters in MFP 8.0 asynchronously?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Here I am trying to invoke multiple js adapters from java adapter asynchronously but fails to get the response object. Can anyone help me on this.I tried this using Callable and Future of java.

```
public JSONArray getResourceDataAsync() throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException
    HttpUriRequest request = adaptersAPI.createJavascriptAdapterRequest(randNumberAdapter, "getEmpDetails");
    addJsAdapterRequest(request);

    request = adaptersAPI.createJavascriptAdapterRequest(randTextAdapter, "getJson");
    addJsAdapterRequest(request);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Inside Thread Run method");
            HttpUriRequest req = adaptersAPI.createJavascriptAdapterRequest(randNumberAdapter, "getEmpDetails");
            HttpResponse res=null;
            try {
                res = adaptersAPI.executeAdapterRequest(req);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JSONObject object=null;
            try {
                object = adaptersAPI.getResponseAsJSON(res);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("The response from Thread Implementation is  -->" + object);
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Did you see this link  https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/it/foundation/8.0/adapters/advanced-adapter-usage-mashup/  ?

Comment: Sample demo https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/AdaptersMashup

Comment: @manjunathkallannavar yes. I have read all those docs and also implemented the above scenario . for synchronous calls made from java adapter it works but in case of passing the request through thread , it fails. That is why am asking about the asynchronous implementation and if this is possible using mfp apis.

Answer (score 0):

Adapter mashup calls - where one adapter calls another deployed adapter , can only be done synchronously. Asynchronous calling is not supported. What you have observed is expected.

The right way is to use the following code:

```
HttpUriRequest req = adaptersAPI.createJavascriptAdapterRequest(AdapterName, ProcedureName, [parameters]);
org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = adaptersAPI.executeAdapterRequest(req);
JSONObject jsonObj = adaptersAPI.getResponseAsJSON(response);
```

The details are [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/advanced-adapter-usage-mashup/#calling-a-javascript-adapter-procedure-from-a-java-adapter).

Comment: Is it possible to do that using HttpClient where we directly hit the rest end points from java adapter  and not using the above methods. can we make async call that way infact integrating it with spring.

Comment: It can be done.But why do you want to do all this? If the adapter endpoint you are calling is protected ( if not custom, there is always default protection), you will receive a challenge as response. Within your calling adapter you cannot handle it - since adapters expect to get an OAuth token. Alternatively, you can explicitly turn off OAuth security for your second endpoint.

Comment: In my project there are many backend apis that are invoked from js adapters using MFP.Server.invokeHttp() method synchronously and that takes a lot of time in execution , to make it a bit fast a wanted to call the javascript adapters from a java adapter and making the js adapter call async so that all the backend services can run on multiple threads and after completion each can return the response and then I can combine the responses into a single json array that could be returned to client app. So if you have suggestion how to do it , pls help.

Comment: You can do this if your JS adapter procedures are explicitly marked unprotected.  Use the approach mentioned here:
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2018/11/29/Reuse-7.xAdapterAuth-in-MFP80/